# Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/6}{\sin}^{n}x~dx$ = 0

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits

Prove that the $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/6}{\sin}^{n}x~dx = 0$. Make use of the following theorem:

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions in $R[a, b]$. Suppose the sequence converges uniformly on $[a, b]$ to the function f . Then $f\in R[a, b]$ and $\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx \Rightarrow \int_{a}^{b}f(x)~dx$

You may assume $\sin(x)$ is continuous.

I am not sure exactly how to start this proof. I think I would need to first find the pointwise limit, which I believe is $0$.

Comment: Except where $|\sin x|=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $x\in [0,\pi/6]$, we have

$$|\sin^n(x)|\le \frac1{2^n}<\epsilon$$

whenever $n>\frac{-\log(\epsilon)}{\log(2)}$.  Therefore, $\sin^n(x)$ converges uniformly to $0$ for $x\in[0,\pi/6]$.

Finally, using the given theorem we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^{\pi/6}\sin^n(x)\,dx&=\int_0^{\pi/6}\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin^n(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/6}(0)\,dx\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 7):

*Alternatively*, one may observe that
$$
0\le \sin x \leq \frac12,\qquad x \in \left[0,\frac{\pi}6\right],
$$ giving
$$
0\le \int_0^{\pi/6}\sin^n x \:dx\leq \int_0^{\pi/6}\frac1{2^n}\:dx.
$$

Comment: From there, referring to the last line, could I deduce that since the middle integral is $\leq$ than the right integral and the middle integral is $\geq$ 0, then it must converge to 0?

Comment: Since $1\over{2^n}$ converges to 0 as $n\to \infty$

Comment: You have that the given integral, say $I$, satisfies $0\le I \le \dfrac{\pi}6 \cdot \dfrac1{2^n}$, then you may conclude with the squeeze theorem.

Comment: If I were to involve the theorem, would that go on a completely different track than what you did? Could I incorporate it while using your method, which I find elegant.

Comment: Gotta love the squeeze theorem. Love this solution!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> This is a nice appplication of [$\underline{Laplace\,'s\ Method}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method):

\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/6}\sin^{n}\pars{x}\,\dd x =
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/6}\sin^{n}\pars{{\pi \over 6} - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/6}
\exp\pars{n\ln\pars{\sin\pars{{\pi \over 6} - x}}}\,\dd x =
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/6}
\exp\pars{n\ln\pars{{1 \over 2} - {\root{3} \over 2}\,x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/6}
\exp\pars{-n\ln\pars{2} - n\root{3}x}\,\dd x =
\lim_{n\to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over 2^{n}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-\root{3}nx}\,\dd x} = \bbx{\ds{0}}
\end{align}